# Sublime 3 Stopped Working on Ubuntu 14.04 after System Crash

Tags: 14.04, unity, sublime-text

Aloha - of course this could be a sublime text issue, but here goes the issue just in case someone can point me in the right direction.

I have been using Sublime 3 on Ubuntu without issue. Yesterday my computer froze up and I had to hard reboot. Sublime text was running when I had to do the hard boot. Then when computer reloaded, I could not open sublime text, the icon shows in the left sidebar as sublime text is running when I open it, and when I use "alt + tab" to rotate through open applications it is there as an icon. However the application is just not actually opening for me to use it, the GUI is just not showing. If I "alt+tab" to it, nothing.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Sublime Text 3 also, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If an application does not work after a crash

Remove `~/.config/sublime-text-3`, immediately log out and back in. I am pretty sure it will work then.

In these situations, local files can get corrupted, rather then the global ones. The fact that you reinstalled `Sublime Text` with no success is another indication the cause is locally.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the previous answer is a bit over the top. It's likely enough to delete the `.sublime-session` files in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local`. Your configuration will stay intact, as will all installed packages and the license data (if available.)